# Which JDK's release should I use when coding a sonar plugin?

Tags: java, java-7, sonarqube, java-6

I'm currently coding a plugin for sonar ( custom rules ) . Which JDK and API should I use in order to be compatible for teh majority of sonar instances ? JDK6 ?

Thanks for your response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said above you can use Java6. Indeed you **must** use Java6.
When a sonar analysis is launched, the launcher of the analysis (sonar runner or maven) will use your sonar instance as a plugin repository. This means that each jar plugins will be downloaded on the machine performing the analysis. Then each plugin will be asked if it should be executed or not.
Hence, if a plugin is built using Java7, you need to run sonar using Java7 and you also need to run any analysis with Java7, even if this plugin is disabled.

Answer (score 4):

From the Sonar website

> Prerequisite
>
> The only prerequisite for running Sonar is to have Java (Oracle JRE 6
>   onwards) installed on your machine.

Check more details [here](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Requirements)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Java 6 onwards` It is also mentioned in the [SONAR](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Requirements) web site.